# Why require(minter == msg.sender) always throw error? I used the correct address as sender

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-721

I created an contract , source code is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";


contract MyTestNft is ERC721URIStorage {
    uint256 private _tokensCount = 0;
    address public minter = address(0);

    event LogMint(address to, uint256 tokenId, uint256 tokensCount, address minter, address sender);

    modifier onlyMinter(){
        require(
            minter == msg.sender,
            'Invalid Minter: ...'
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor() ERC721("MyTestNft", "MTN") {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(address to) external onlyMinter {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokensCount + 1;
        _mint(to, tokenId);
        _tokensCount = tokenId;
        emit LogMint(to, tokenId, _tokensCount, minter, msg.sender);
    }

}
```

when published this contract via `remix`, and call the `mint` method, everything is fine.

However, if I call this contract's `mint` method via `javascript web3.js`, EVM always complaints that `Invalid Minter` ( `minter == msg.sender` )

my call.js looks like:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const fs = require('fs')

async function main(file_name_without_suffix, contract_address){
  const { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("build/contracts/" +file_name_without_suffix+'.json'))
  const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK

  // step1. 初始化web3 实例，增加json rpc server
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      `https://${network}.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`
    )
  )

  // step2. 创建signer
  const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(  process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY)
  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer)

  // step3. 创建contract, abi是关键
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract( abi, contract_address)

  let result = ''
  result = await contract.methods.minter().call()
  console.info("minter: ", result)
  result = await contract.methods.name().call()
  console.info("name: ", result)
  result = await contract.methods.symbol().call()
  console.info("symbol: ", result)

  console.info("--- signer:", signer)

  let tx = ''
  tx = await contract.methods.mint('0xc0dD5021e298dB57bEF361C735cd1C04cef2E48A')
  let from = signer.address
  // let from = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0]
  console.info("== now let's mine one: ,from: ", from)
  result = await tx
    .send({from: from, gas: await tx.estimateGas()})
    .once("transactionHash" , (txHash) => {
      console.info("mining transaction...", txHash)
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.info("--- on error: ", error)
    })
  console.info("mint result: ", result)

}

require('dotenv').config()

main(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]).then( () => process.exit(0) )
```

I deploy this contract to: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x81ec27587694f9996a69dc26230643dd619cfaba

and when I run this script by `node call.js MyTestNft 0x494B51eA8c1a6e9994274141977186c809c68fb5`

it always shows the error:

```
minter:  0xc0dD5021e298dB57bEF361C735cd1C04cef2E48A
name:  MyTestNft
symbol:  MTN
--- signer: {
  address: '0xc0dD5021e298dB57bEF361C735cd1C04cef2E48A',
  privateKey: '0xa7d856cf836a71422df6a76837e1c67022aba9bda349b0a9e85a496cb321????',
  signTransaction: [Function: signTransaction],
  sign: [Function: sign],
  encrypt: [Function: encrypt]
}
== now let's mine one: ,from:  0xc0dD5021e298dB57bEF361C735cd1C04cef2E48A
/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28
        var err = new Error('Returned error: ' + message);
                  ^

Error: Returned error: execution reverted: Invalid Minter: ...
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/workspace/test_erc_721_in_truffle/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  data: '0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013496e76616c6964204d696e7465723a202e2e2e00000000000000000000000000'
}
```

so, any ideas? thank you so much!

p.s. If I remove the modifier at the function declaration, e.g.

```
    function mint(address to) external {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokensCount + 1;
        _mint(to, tokenId);
        _tokensCount = tokenId;
        emit LogMint(to, tokenId, _tokensCount, minter, msg.sender);
    }
```

everything looks fine! and it would give the event log, showed the `minter` is the same as `msg.sender`. e.g. ( https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4db740f0b927ffa17e50003d59487670b173b075f8c57f840d81c038b8e68511#eventlog  )

[image]

updated 1:

I found it OK under `truffle's local node`, not OK in `goerli + infura`.

updated 2:

I found it OK under `local ganache`. I am thinking if goerli has bug.

Comment: Not an answer but [consider using custom errors instead of revert reason strings](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/). Compared to revert reason strings, custom errors are easier to work with, more gas efficient, and more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally, 2 months later, I found solution: don't use `web3.js`, use `ethers` instead.

It's a bug for `web3.js`.

OLD ANSWER:

I think this is a bug or maybe the network connection problems for goerli network.

I tested the same code on `truffle's local node`, also on `ganache`, both of them are running ok.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to the question is that the error is generated by the `estimateGas` function and not the `send` function.

Based on the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas), you need to pass the `from` address `await tx.estimateGas({from: '0x.....'})` which makes sense as this info is not known yet to estimate the gas.

You can easily tested (for sanity reasons) by adding a fixed gas value instead of using the `estimateGas` function.